# Receber uma string e colocar chaves nela

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou com um script que recebe uma string. Eu preciso receber essa string e adicionar em suas extremidades chaves. Estou com problema quando coloco:

```
variavel = input('informe um valor')
print(f'{variavel} aqui vem um texto.')
```

Quero que o retorno da função `print()` apareça essas chaves, sem que o usuário tenha que digitar elas. Da forma acima, aparece a variável conforme foi digitada pelo usuário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de uma [*f-string*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), os caracteres `{` e `}` servem para indicar que você vai usar o valor da expressão que estiver entre eles. Se quiser que os próprios caracteres `{` e `}` sejam impressos, você deve escrevê-los como `{{` e `}}`. Então ficaria:

```
variavel = input('informe um valor')
print(f'{{{variavel}}} aqui vem um texto.')
```

Os dois primeiros `{{` servem para imprimir o caractere `{`, e o terceiro `{` faz parte da expressão `{variavel}`, que é substituído pelo valor da variável. Em seguida, os dois últimos `}}` servem para imprimir o caractere `}`.

Se o usuário digitar "abc", por exemplo, a saída será:

```
{abc} aqui vem um texto.
```

---

Claro que você também pode usar concatenação, como indica a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444285/112052).

Comment: Obrigado! não conhecia essa parte de f-string.

Answer (score 6):

Talvez tenha se confundido com a *f-strings* que usam essa sintaxe e achou que ela colocaria as chaves, mas é justamente o oposto, elas são especiais nesse mecanismo. È possível usá-lo e ainda consegui o que deseja, mas não me parece muito conveniente (veja as demais respostas).

O simples me parece o mais adequado, faça uma concatenação simples:

```
variavel = input('informe um valor')
print('{' + variavel + '} se quiser pode ter um texto aqui')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/h3Ketb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ConcatenationSimplec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Concatenation.py).

Comment: Obrigado! É isso mesmo!

Answer (score 4):

Para apresentar os caracteres `{` e `}` de forma literal você precisará "escapar" eles adicionando o mesmo carácter uma segunda vez.
Ou seja, para apresentar o valor `{` você precisa escrever `{{`

Como você ainda deseja utilizar a interpolação, você precisará utilizar 3 caracteres.
Seu código vai ficar desta forma:

```
print(f'{{{variavel}}} aqui vem um texto.')
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua ajuda!